# Google Places' Search Functionality Is Not Retrieving The Same Data As Google Maps'

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have implemented the Google Places API. If I search for "Cafes near my location" in Google Maps I get a list of results, whereas, when I perform the same search with Google Places I get 0 results.

I also used a Place.TYPE_CAFE PlaceFilter (i.e. a filter for cafes) in my implementation of Google Places and it returns 0 results for cafes even though there are at least 2 cafes within 0.5 miles of my location according to Google Maps when I search for "Cafes near my location"

Here is my implementation of the PlaceFilter with the Places.PlaceDetectionApi

```
     ArrayList<Integer> placeType = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     placeType.add(Integer.parseInt(""+Place.TYPE_CAFE));

    PlaceFilter placeFilter = new PlaceFilter(placeType,false,null,null) ;

    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, placeFilter);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i("placesAPI", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    })
```

**Problem in a nutshell:** How do I make the Google Places' search functionality return as many places as Google Maps' ?

If you need any more code let me know,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Places API may have improved since I asked this question but one solution to this problem is to use the Google Maps Web API.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Place Autocomplete service in the  [Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) and you can also get palces near by your location using  [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests). Autocomplete returns place predictions in response to user search queries. As the user types, the autocomplete service returns suggestions for places to points of interest.

Here's a sample tutorial showing nearby places using Google Places API and Google Maps Android V2: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I implemented Place Autocomplete widget and it still doesn't return any results for the search 'Cafes near my location'. But it does find at least some specific places if I search for them. I implemented the Google Maps Web API, and it is able to return results for the search  'Cafes near my location'. Why do you think the Places API can't give the same search results as the Google Maps Web API ? Thanks in advance